# How to dis-connect and then re-connect a postgres tablespace?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

Is it possible to dis-connect and re-connect a `POSTGRES` tablespace and all the associated objects within that tablespace?

I have a Postgres database with two tablespaces, one on a high-speed SSD drive (I've named this FASTSPACE) , and the other on a slower, traditional magnetic HDD (named SLOWSPACE). The slower tablespace is reserved for large volumes of historic data which is rarely accessed.

Is it possible to temporarily disconnect `SLOWSPACE`, with the intention of reconnecting it at a later date? the `DROP TABLESPACE` documentation can only be used once all database objects within it have been dropped.

I'm aware that I can backup all the tables in `SLOWSPACE`, then delete them, and then `DROP` the tablespace, however this will take time (there are several Terabytes of data). If I then need the archived data again I'll have create a new version of the `SLOWSPACE` tablespace from blank, then re-create all the objects from the backups. Again, this will take time.

Is there any way of temporarily disconnecting `SLOWSPACE` from the database - whilst still leaving the rest of the database up and running?

Update - happy to accept Franks Heikens two letter answer - 'no'

Comment: Short answer: No. What I do in situations like this, is an export to CSV and connect to these CSV files using a foreign data wrapper reading these CSV-files. Then it looks like a table, but it's just a file on some (slow) storage outside the database.

Comment: For the reasons why you can't do this see [Tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) and look for the **Warning** block.